¿Por qué me dice NaN como error en Javascript al llamar a una función?
Estoy llamando a esta función y me devuelve NaN, lo que sería no es un número, ¿por qué si estoy mandando especificamente un 10?


function sumar(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}
  
console.log(sumar(10));




Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! pero esa funcion recibe dos parametros, no uno... te dice nan, porque intenta sumar un parametro que no existe...

Estás mandando 10 y undefined, cómo sumas 10 y undefined?? Tu función tiene dos parámetros!

El operador + en JavaScript hace dos funciones, la suma de números y la concatenación de cadenas. En ambos casos, lo primero que hace es obligar (coerce) a que ambos operandos sean tipos primitivos.
Este proceso llamado Number Coercion tiene una serie de normas, y una de ellas es que si se pasa un valor undefined, se tiene que convertir en NaN.
Como no has pasado un parámetro a la función, el motor de JavaScript entiende que el segundo parámetro es undefined, y el operador de suma obliga a que ese valor sea NaN. Por último sumar cualquier valor a NaN, devuelve NaN.
Para evitar esto, llama a tu función con un segundo parámetro que valga 0, o cambia la función para que si el segundo parámetro no está definido lo interprete como 0 en lugar de como NaN.
Puedes ver las reglas de Number Coercion de forma resumida son:

Los números no se modifican.
undefined se convierte en NaN
null se convierte en 0.
true se convierte en 1 y false en 0.
Las cadenas se convierten analizando primero si contienen un número literal. Si falla, se convierte en NaN
Cadenas vacías o que contengan solo espacios en blanco se convierten en 0.
BigInts lanzan un TypeError para prevenir fallos de precisión.
Symbols lanzan un TypeError.
Los objetos primero se convierten a privitiva llamando a sus método [@@toPrimitive]() (con "number" como pista), valueOf(), y toString() en ese orden. La primitiva resultante se convierte en número.

Más info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition


la cerre porque pense que era un error de que le faltaba un parametro, porque especificamente OP dice que le esta mandando un numero (y no dos).. si te parece la reabro, pero a mi entender no tiene mucho sentido.. la respuesta esta bien.. pero la pregunta me parece que apuntaba a otro lado..

Para mi es una pregunta genuina que merece la respuesta. La respuesta es buena, pero empieza por el final. En mi opinión sería mejor si primero explica que la función requiere dos parámetros, que solo se pasa uno y por tanto el segundo toma el valor indefinido, y de allí el resto de la explicación, que es excelente.

igual sigo que creyendo que OP confundio algo mucho menos complejo que esto, y es que necesita 2 parametros, no uno.. fijense que pone que "le mando el numero"...

Es tonta pero es valida... he visto peores con votos positivos incluso ...

No es tonta, es una pregunta genuina de alguien que está estudiando/aprendiendo a programar con un detalle que se paso por alto o no se entendió muy bien, a todos nos pasó algo así (y nos seguirá pasando). No hagamos que SO en español sea como en SO en inglés.

Como dicen todos, el error es que la funcion recibe 2 parametros y le estás pasando 1. Al intentar sumar undefined da ese error.
Se puede arreglar asignando un valor por defecto a los parametros de la función, así si no se le manda nada, le asigna ese valor por defecto


    function sumar(a = 0, b = 0){
        return a + b;
    }

    console.log(sumar(10));




El error es simple, le estas pasando solo 1 numero a la funcion para que se ejecute y necesita que le pases 2.
    function sumar(a, b) {
    return a + b;
 }
   
 console.log(sumar(10,2));

Asi deberia devolver 12 por consola. En tu caso vos solo le pasabas un 10 por parametro por eso da NaN
